# Simple usage wonder, can i get the cursor to stop auto selecting a blank single space after autocompleting a Dot notation?

Tags: dataweave

I'm new to Anypoint Studio and Dataweave so I don't know if its a dumb question, but when I'm typing out a field, and the UI offers to autofill the available paths in the Dot Notation... it automatically selects a single space that is immediately removed when you type the next thing.

The reason this is an issue is that Anypoint won't give you a preview if you have any red flags in the script, so when I'm troubleshooting, I have to push the comma out several blank spaces so that the UI doesn't auto-kill it resulting in a red flag and no preview.

Again I know this is probably a dumb question that could be asked to just Anypoint, but I prefer to ask real folks with real minds that can provide any extra thoughts or tips.

Comment: It's a bug introduced since 7.7 version of Studio ( I think ). Hopefully it will be fixed soon.  I usually just press the right arrow cursor key to clean up the selected character.  It's second nature now days 

Comment: Ah, thanks. So bizarre how user-unfriendly the setup can be sometimes.